# no se pueden ejecutar los ficheros jnlp en openJDK11

Tags: java, java-11, jnlp

Tras instalar openJDK11 en WIndows10 no se pueden ejecutar los ficheros jnlp ni las descargas de tipo mime application/x-java-jnlp-file.

¿ Sabéis si debo instalar algún plugin o bajar algún paquete añadido?

Comment: Los applets y JNLP no son soportados [desde Java 11](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web), tendrás que mantenerte en una versión anterior de Java o migrar esas aplicaciones a aplicaciones *normales* de escritorio

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, hay alguna documentación oficial de Oracle donde informarme?

Comment: Vale, perdón por la novatada. Ya veo que me lo has dejado en el comment. Gracias de nuevo!

Answer (score 0):

A partir de Java 11 ya no se soporta JNLP.

Dependiendo del tipo de tu aplicación puedes migrar de diferentes maneras.

Si es una aplicación que necesitas que se autoactualice y corra en la máquina de tu cliente podrías considerar usar [GetDown](https://github.com/threerings/getdown).

Karakun por su parte está desarrollando una alternativa llamada [Open Web Start](https://github.com/karakun/OpenWebStart) que de momento no está lista, pero puedes contribuir a su desarrollo.